# Algorithm package not found

Tags: miktex, installing, update

I want to use the `algorithm`-package for writing pseudo code. Yesterday, I downloaded MiKTeX and now I am getting this message. But when I click install, nothing is happening.

[image: Package not found]

```
    \documentclass{dutmsc}%
    \mscDepartment{Transport \& Planning}%
    \mscFaculty{Civil Engineering and Geosciences}%
    \mscName{Lenin Mishra}%
    \mscDate{30/08/2016}%
    \mscTitle{Maneuvering of Automated Vehicles in an Unsignalized      Intersection}%
    \mscSubTitle{A Distributed Control Strategy}% can be left empty
    \ifpdf
      \mscBackPicture{./figs/merlin_landing_3_pdf}    % eps of 21 * 29.7 cm
    \else
      \mscBackPicture{./figs/merlin_landing_3}    % pdf version of the cover background
    \fi
    \mscReaderOne{prof.dr.ir. P.R. Of}
    \mscReaderTwo{dr.ir. D.A.I. Ly Supervisor}
    \mscReaderThree{ir. G.U. Est}
    \mscReaderFour{ir. Reader Four}
    \loflotintoc{1}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \usepackage[preserveurlmacro]{breakurl}%
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \newcommand{\cc}[1]{\:\mathcal{C}_{#1}}%
    \newcommand{\cs}[1]{\:\mathcal{S}_{#1}}%
    \newcommand{\ct}[1]{\:\mathcal{T}_{#1}}%
    \newcommand{\matlab}{\textsc{Matlab} }
    \makenomenclature
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
        citecolor=darkblue,
        urlcolor=darkred,
        linkcolor=darkblue,
        menucolor=darkblue,
        anchorcolor=red,
        pagecolor=cyan,
        pdfborder={0 0 0},
        bookmarksnumbered=true,
        breaklinks=true,
        pdfauthor={\mscname},           % value of \mscName
        pdftitle={\msctitle},           % value of \mscTitle
        pdfkeywords={\msckeywords}}     % value of \mscKeywords

    \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
    \begin{document}%



    \frontmatter%

       \maketitle%

       \include{summary}%
       \cleardoublepage%

\include{acknowledgements}%
\cleardoublepage%
% 
% table of contents, list of figures and list of tables
\tocloflot%
%
% Nomenclature
\printnomencl%
\cleardoublepage%
%
%
\mainmatter%
%
% parts are not necessary for a thesis
%
% first chapter
\include{chap_introduction}%
\include{chap_Literature_Review}%
\include{chap_Development_of_the_cooperative_strategy}%
%
% add more chapters here
%\include{chap_theory}
%
%
% Bibliography
\printbib{biblio}%
%
\appendix%
%
% and some appendices here
\include{app_math_model}%
%
%
\backmatter%
%
% index file here (not needed for a MSc thesis)
%
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Guys, I tried to download from the Miktex Package manager. It says that "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it ". It also says that "="connect failed in tcp_connect()". Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Have you tried with another repository ?

Comment: @JérômeDequeker Could you please explain, what do you mean by repository ? I am using Latex for less than a week now. So, it might be difficult for me to understand the specific terms.

Comment: On the *Package installation* window, what append if you click on *Change...* ?

Comment: @JérômeDequeker When I click on change, there are three options. The first option says that it will be installed from the internet. If I click that, it says the error mentioned in the first comment. The next option is that packages shall be installed from a directory. The third says that it will be installed from a DVD. I don't have a DVD, so the last option is ruled out. I am not sure how to use the second option. Could you please help me to install it properly ?

Comment: @JérômeDequeker http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302737/permission-denied-to-install-algorithm-packages

Comment: The internet option should work.
Is there a problem with your fire-wall or antivirus ?
http://miktex.10937.n7.nabble.com/Connectivity-error-td8201.html

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday the repository was down. This might have been the problem.
Another reason for this message may be the inappropriate proxy configuration.
If you are using a proxy server for connecting to the interenet you should click the "change" button in the package installation dialog and enter the settings of your proxy server there.
Another possibility for doing this is given in the MikTeX update manager ("connection settings" button).